# How to return NSLocalizedString as write in the code

Tags: objective-c, nslocalizedstring

Is there a way to get a NSLocalizedString in its untranslated states, for example getting it from a NSTexfield/label or popup button as below:

```
_mylabel.stringValue
```

or

```
[_myPopupButton titleOfSelectedItem];
```

Obviously returns a translated string depending on the current OS language. 
This is inconvenient if I want to know and use a statement comparing what I find at the time, whereas users can also translate or adjust to their liking the stringsfile. 
Any suggestion or workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Initially the problem was that I used "NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults" to save what was on the buttons on a plist, so when I restart the app would have taken those descriptions initially were created using simple strings if the plist did not contain all the dictionary needed (to return into my button), as if app was open for the first time).

It's enough to localize everything, even when re-reading or create the "empty" settings, so it does not matter if the preferences are written in another language: my button now return what the app found on the plist created by "NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults"!

(sorry for my poor English)